White Block Appearing on Scroll in Telegram Mini App
I encountered an issue where Telegram Mini app initially has a default scroll. To remove the scroll, I applied overflow: hidden to the body elements because, without this, you can scroll the page, making it seem like the Telegram window is not optimized for the device.
To address this, I created a Page Wrapper component with a height of 100vh and enabled automatic scrolling within it. This setup makes the content appear to occupy the entire page initially, with the scroll contained within the Page Wrapper.
However, I encountered a problem: when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page on a mobile device and then slowly scrolls back up, a white block appears. The issue disappears if I remove the overflow: hidden from the body, but this isn’t a viable solution for me. Without overflow: hidden, it seems like the Telegram window itself is being scrolled first, whereas I need the content to be displayed in full screen without affecting the Telegram window.
Default css code

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background: rgba(247, 246, 255, 1);
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


Page Component
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import PageTitle from '../../page-title';
import classes from './style.module.scss';

interface PageWrapperProps {
  title: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}
const Page = ({ children, title }: PageWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.page}>
      <PageTitle title={title} />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;

Page component styles
.page {
  padding: 12px 16px 100px 16px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: rgba(247, 246, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  color: $white;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}


Same problem. And for me problem persists only on iOS, cant recreate it on android
